# Can a response to an http request error be gziped?

Tags: http, http-headers, gzip, http-error

When trying to execute an http request that causes a 400 Bad Request error, an nginx server returns the "400 Bad Request", a Content-Encoding: gzip, and the response in a non-encoded format.

So because of the Content-Encoding: gzip my code wraps the response with a GZIPInputStream which throws an error.

My question is: is gzip a valid encoding when the status code is not "200 OK"?  if not, I can simply check for the status code and not try to gzip if anything other than 200 was returned.

Are there rules/guidelines about this? Is this documented anywhere?

TIA

Comment: gzip is valid in any response code, but in any way you can make decigion using only status code(actually I don't know why you need content when status code is not 200)

Comment: this is for a code library for other developers to use, so when possible we should give them as much information back as possible, including body of requests that result in an error.

Comment: @ice _"actually I don't know why you need content when status code is not 200"_ - because 301, 302, 303: _"the entity of the response SHOULD contain a short hypertext note with a hyperlink to the new URI(s)."_, 403: _"If [...] the server wishes to make public why the request has not been fulfilled, it SHOULD describe the reason for the refusal in the entity"_, ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it is a valid encoding. Content-Encoding (and Transfer-Encoding) are orthogonal to status codes.